# GetOleDbSchemaTable Foreign Keys on Sql Server 2005

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, schema, oledb

I'm trying to get the Foreign Keys for a table in my SQL Server 2005 database. I'm using the GetOleDbSchemaTable function right now:

```
DataTable schemaTable = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(
        OleDbSchemaGuid.Foreign_Keys,
        new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
```

This pulls back the right foreign keys, the only problem is that the UpdateRule and DeleteRule are set to "No Action". If I browse to the same table in SSMS I can see that my DeleteRule is "Set NULL". Does the GetOleDbSchemaTable function not return the proper foreign key rules ? Has any one else ran into this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why OleDb would return incorrect information, but have you tried using `SqlConnection` and `GetSchema` instead?  They're MSSQL specific so may yield better results.